# Desktop environment from debian backports

Tags: debian, backports

I'm newbie in debian backports. I see lot of advantages of this, but is it possible to install newer versions of GNOME / KDE / XFCE etc.? I know, that backports include kernel, apps, but I can't find packages for desktop environments. Is there any solution? I don't want to use Debiab Bullseye (testing).

Comment: Why choose a distro which sticks to outdated software? Almost daily someone has issues with Debian: either because of its relatively old kernel or something similar and I just don't understand why people don't use Ubuntu 20.10 instead.

Comment: Tip: [Don't suffer from shiny new stuff syndrome](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_suffer_from_Shiny_New_Stuff_Syndrome)

Answer (score 1):

A few [GNOME](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/gnome/) and [KDE](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/kde/) packages have been backported, but full desktop environments are extremely unlikely to be backported even if you ask for them.

Packages are backported to serve specific use-cases or fix problems which aren’t severe enough to warrant a point-release update but affect a large number of users, assuming someone is willing to take on the work involved. Maintaining desktop environments takes a considerable amount of effort, and backporting them is probably not worth it — beyond the desktop environments themselves, a significant number of supporting packages would have to be backported too, and the result would have to be extensively tested.

If you want a distribution with the latest desktop environments, you’ll have to run something other than Debian stable.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious if it's possible.